# On a Mac, a webpage can be printed as a PDF file, but images are chopped up across pages... any solution?

Tags: macos, pdf, archiving, webpage

Such as the page for Rails 3.0 tutorial:

> http://railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning

when printed as a PDF using Firefox, Chrome, or Safari on a Mac, the images get all chopped up across page boundry.

I like to print as PDF so that it can be highlighted by Mac's Preview or by Windows's Foxit Reader.  The other way is to save it using Safari as webarchive, but then it is not highlight-able... and less supported across platforms (such as Linux)

Is there any solution?

Comment: I don't think it is legal to print a webpage as PDF instead of buying it like they offer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, you could actually *buy the PDF they have for sale*. It's formatted properly (images are all complete on single pages) and you'd be able to highlight it as you wish.

Alternatively, I noticed just now that Word 2008 can read .webarchive files if you open them as HTML. (Quite fascinating, actually.) Word automatically will then force a break if images go off the page.